Is this Proof for the Integral of Binomial Coefficients Correct?
I am trying to learn proof techniques and terminology so I can formally state math concepts with rigor. I saw this video on youtube, where the presenter proves:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {n \choose x} dx = 2^n, \space \{x, n \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\}  $$
Video source:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG06EyHJYlE&lc=UgwSdQnvh-Z28fYXtUl4AaABAg
While I followed the video, I thought of a different (albeit weaker) proof using simpler concepts, which follows below (sorry it's a picture, I wanted to use packages). My question is twofold:
Is this proof correct?
Is this proof good? (opinion question).

Is the proof clear?
Is the proof structured well?
Is the notation correct/standard?
Would the proof be made better with the addition/removal of anything?


First Try
This had some major issues with how I handled integrals.


Second Try


You are conflating an integral with a sum: There is no reason to believe a priori that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \binom{n}{x} ,dx = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}$, as the left hand side is an integral over all real values of $x$. So at the very least for it to make sense, you need to have a definition of $\binom{n}{x}$ that makes sense for non-integer values of $x$...

In the same vein, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \binom{n}{x}, {x, n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}}$ does not make sense: $x$ is not a free variable in the integral. You can (and need) to specify what values $n$ takes, but the integral "demands" that $x$ take all possible real values.

@arkeet: Hmm, I see your points. Both of your comments are true, the current line of reasoning is faulty. I wanted to restrict the integral of ${n \choose x}dx$ to just use integer values of n,x, but I now see that that conflicts with how integrals work. It seems like I can still salvage something by changing the integral to a summation, which I added to the question as a second try. Thank you for both of your inputs.

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

Write ${n \choose x}$ as an integral over $\left(-\pi, \pi\right)$.  Switch the integrals. You get a  Dirac Delta which simplifies the business.

See https://mathoverflow.net/a/255058/ for another proof.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{n \choose x}\dd x} =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\pars{1 + \expo{\ic\phi}}^{n} \over \expo{\ic x\phi}}{\dd\phi \over 2\pi}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\pars{1 + \expo{\ic\phi}}^{n}\,\
\overbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic\phi x}\,
{\dd x \over 2\pi}}^{\ds{\delta\pars{\phi}}}}\,\
\,\dd\phi = \pars{1 + \expo{\ic 0}}^{n} = \bbx{\color{#44f}{2^{n}}} \\ &
\end{align}
